# Кнопки у фрагментов кода

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Надписи на кнопках над фрагментами кода гласят:

- **<kbd>Выполнить фрагмент кода</kbd>**
- **<kbd>Копировать фрагмент кода в ответ</kbd>**
- **<kbd>Скрыть результаты</kbd>**

(Третья кнопка появляется после нажатия на первую кнопку.)

Кнопки явно рисовались с планом быть размещёнными на одной строке, однако в русской локализации они оказались нечеловеческого размера. Ну вот хотя бы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419048 Если выполнить код, то кнопки занимают чуть ли не больше места, чем поле для результатов.

Предлагаю убрать мусор из названий:

- **<kbd>Выполнить код</kbd>**
- **<kbd>Копировать код в ответ</kbd>**
- **<kbd>Скрыть результаты</kbd>**

P.S. Мне до сих пор разрывает мозг от понятия "фрагмент кода". Учитывая, как часто мне приходится исправлять сообщения новичков, использующих кнопку не по назначению (или наоборот не использующих по назначению), то у меня возникает ощущение, что в своих объясняющих комментариях я несу какую-то тарабарщину:

> Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

Причём для <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> даже кнопки на тулбаре нет...

Comment: Перевод текста поправил, спасибо! Пожалуйста, раскройте подробнее замечание по поводу термина "фрагмент кода".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Слова "фрагмент кода" никаким образом не соотносятся с фактическим значением — самодостаточным набором HTML+JS+CSS с наглядной демонстрацией. Из-за этого возникает путаница.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Наверное, имеет смысл постить хотя бы минимальный ответ, а не только добавлять тег, чтобы статус вопроса изменился и с точки зрения движка (сейчас вопрос находится в категории "Без ответа").